# Input array of usernames into MongoDB and get back array of ids that is the same size, with null or false for non-existing usernames

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am using Meteor JS. I want to input an array of usernames into MongoDB and get back an array of ids that is the same size, with null or false for the elements corresponding to non-existing usernames. Will the following code do the job?

```
var userIds = Meteor.users.find({ username: { $in: usernameArray } }).map(function(item){ return item._id; });
```

If so, can I also find the index of the non-existing username by something like

```
var badUsernames = userIds.indexOf(null);
```

Just to clarify some more: I want to know if Meteor.users.find couldn't find some of the users by the usernameArray input. Will the userIds array even contain the elements corresponding to the invalid user ids?

Comment: Well no. You are issuing a query that "asks" to match the "users" you provide, so in just about every ( well a actually, every ) database system you can think of will do what you asked. So what are you really asking? How to get what matches and what does not match in one result? Or can you really just live with two queries?

Comment: Yes, I want to know what matched and doesn't match in one query. If that is too complicated, I'll settle for two queries. Thanks, Neil

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the user list, you can `filter` it:

```
var goodUserIds = userIds.filter(function(id){
    return !!id;
});
```

Reverse the condition to get invalid user ids.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jrhzwa6/1/

Comment: Hi @Johan, thanks for your response. Just to clarify some more: I want to know if Meteor.users.find couldn't find some of the users by the usernameArray input. Will the userIds array even contain the elements corresponding to the invalid user ids?

Comment: Oh ok. I'm not familiar with Meteor, but since you typed `indexOf(null)` I just assumed that all invalid user ids would be returned as `null`.